# What is the difference between <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/> and <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/>

Tags: android, dynamic-delivery

Could anyone please explain what is the difference between

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

and

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/>
```

also difference between

```
<dist:device-feature dist:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

and

```
<dist:device-feature dist:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your question as there are no differences (on character level) between code line 1/2 and 3/4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I used `getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(FEATURE_CAMERA)` I got a warning indicating to use `FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY` instead of `FEATURE_CAMERA` to include devices with front camera as well.

Thus, **`FEATURE_CAMERA` refers to back-facing camera or the camera that is on the rear side of the smartphone and `FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY` means any camera - it includes front camera as well**

if we use `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>` then devices with only front camera - such as some tablets - will be filtered out.